# Using "with" with inanimate objects

Tags: prepositions, questions

I always hear this whenever I call my printer company. It doesn't sound correct to me.

> Are you with the printer?

How do we correct this sentence?

Comment: **<comments removed>** Please try to avoid answering these questions in comments. If you have an answer, please use the 'answer' function. Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: My comment wasn't intended as "an answer", because at the time I couldn't explain *why* the sequence *"Is the printer **with you**?"* seemed more "correct" to me. All has now become clear with Matt's answer (it depends on whether the object is normally thought of as being in a *fixed* location), but my comment was simply intended to clarify what I felt was "normal/correct", in hopes someone else might provide a rationale for the standard usage. As such, I don't think it should have been deleted, but I don't want to argue the point ad nauseum.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm actually curious if there's a BrE/AmE split on *"with"*.  *"Is the printer with you?"* seems wrong to me.  Is that a quirk of my idiolect or representative of a larger difference, I wonder?

Comment: @snailboat: Back when I started in (UK) tech support, I'd have asked *"Are you **at** the printer?"*, because those early line-printers where as big as fridges (like *mohammed and the mountain*, you went to them, they didn't come to you! :). In later years I might well have said *"Is the printer **with** you?"* because I'd often be speaking to an "on-site systems manager" who might have had the faulty printer brought in to Head Office from a Depot, for example. I doubt there's a UK/US split here - just individual preference for different prepositions.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but it does sound both incorrect and quite humorous :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is *grammatical* (it is an inversion of "Is the printer with you?") but it is not idiomatic English.

If the object is in a *fixed* location (such as a water cooler, or an industrial printer), then the question is normally phrased to ask where you are in relation to the object:

> Are you **at** the printer?
>
> I'm **at** the water cooler.

If the object is movable (such as a small printer, or a remote control), the idiomatic phrasing would be either to ask if you *have* the object:

> Do you have the printer?
>
> Do you have the remote control?

Or to ask if the object is at the same position as you:

> Is the printer there with you?
>
> Is the remote control there with you?

Comment: Would not "Do you have the [object]?" be used for something you can keep in your hands or in your pockets, or that you   generally move near you? A cellphone and a laptop are examples of such objects. A printer is movable, but since it is plugged to the power outlet or to a computer, it is not moved so often.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: More generally, "Do you have the [object]" is for things which are *movable*. For example, "Do you have the car?" would be common, even though a car would not normally fit in your pocket. Things that move rarely or never (such as industrial printers) normally follow the "Are you at the [object]" pattern.

Answer (score 2):

"With the printer" means being with the printer right now. "Are you in [in the same place] with the printer?" Specifically, the company wants to know if they can give you steps to follow to work on the printer right away.

Another way this question is, "Are you at the printer?"

Answer (score 0):

I can be a regional choice that determines which preposition is used. You could use 'at', 'by', or 'with' and be correct. But if you are sitting on the printer making copies of your bum you really should say that you are 'on' the printer.